# How to declare the route instead of file path in C# MVC framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

how can i declare the route instead of the file path ("~/Home/Error.cshtml") for the below mentioned code.

```
 private string _val = "~/Home/Error.cshtml";
```

Comment: I think you want an environmental variable.  You can see you environmental variables in cmd.exe >SET.  Then you can get any variable in your code using : Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("variable name")

Comment: ok thanks for your response